# popup menu background color change not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, material-components-android, material-components

i am begineer in android. I want to popup menu background color change.I try this code for background color change but its not working for me.i don't know why not working this code.

```
<!--popup menu item style-->
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
<style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/colorRegisterHeader</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

//this activity code for popup menu

```
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(HomeActivity.this, v);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(HomeActivity.this);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
```

Comment: background color changing but text color not changing @Gabriele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the **background color** using the `android:popupBackground` attribute.

```
  <!-- Popup Menu -->   
  <style name="MyPopup" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/custom</item>
  </style>
```

You can configure globally this style in your app theme using the [**`popupMenuStyle`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#material-styles) attribute:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
     ....
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopup</item>
  </style>
```

Just [use](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#popup-menus):

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, anchor);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

Currently PopupMenu uses `colorOnPrimary` to define the **textColor**. To change it you have to define a textAppearance:

```
  <style name="MytextAppearanceLargePopupMenu" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```

and then in your app theme adding this attribute:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MytextAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: how can i change text color from popup menu style

Comment: @AbdulQuddusMozumder Updated the answer. Currently you have to define a textAppearance

Answer (score 2):

Add popupMenu style to ur AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Now in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
.............
</application>
```