# Theming Android's Options Menu

Tags: android, colors, background, popupmenu

I am trying to style the Android's options menu. But, I cannot figure out how to change the background color of the popup menu.
I want to get rid of the white borders or to change the color of the borders.
I tried the following things:

```
 <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        ...
    </style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712583/popup-menu-background-color-change-not-working/57712710#57712710 and for the overflow popup menu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844707/customizing-popup-menu-style/58845269#58845269

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this helped me to find a simplier solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<item name="popupMenuBackground">?themeColorPrimary</item>
```

As simple as it is!

If you like to use a style, use:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set

```
<style name="BasicActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/popup</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/popup</item>
</style>

<style name="popup" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
<!-- somewhere in your theme -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BasicActionBar</item>
```

In your action bar theme